# Control the input of the user according to a sample string and get some info from it

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x

I made this Python code that prints a sample string and ensures that the input of the user agrees with the sample, and then do an action with this inputted string, in this case a multiplication table.

I've made this code to practice some Python concepts, and I do not know if I did everything correctly and **"in a pythonic way"**. I'd like to know if there's anything in this code that can be improved and things I could have done otherwise.

```
import re
from time import sleep                                                                                                                                

class StringController(object):                                                                                                                       
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                              
        self.regexp = re.compile('(?i)^show me the multiplication table of [0-9]* from [0-9]* to [0-9]*$')                                            

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Example string: show me the multiplication table of 10 from 5 to 20')
        self.inputedstring = input('Input: ')
        print('-'*50)
        sleep(1)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            print('{}: {}'.format(exc_type.__name__, 'You must use the provided string'))
        else:
            print('-'*50)
        del self.inputedstring

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myobject = StringController()
    while True:
        try:
            with myobject as strcon:
                multiplication_table = list(range(int(myobject.inputedstring.split(' ')[8]), int(myobject.inputedstring.split(' ')[10])+1))
                results = list(map(lambda x : x*int(myobject.inputedstring.split(' ')[6]), multiplication_table))

                if myobject.regexp.match(myobject.inputedstring):
                    print('\n'.join(str(results) for results in results))
                else:
                    raise UserWarning('You must use the provided string')

        except (ValueError, IndexError) as WrongInput:
            print("\n")
            del WrongInput

        finally:
            del strcon
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There's no need for `<pre>` tags; you should just use indentation.  I fixed the `&quot`s as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bug

The regex is flawed, consider this:

```
>>> print(re.match(pat, 'show me the multiplication table of  from  to '))
>>> <re.Match object; span=(0, 46), match='show me the multiplication table of  from  to '>
```

That is because `[0-9]*` matches the digit **zero**, or more times

I suggest to change them with `+` which will match the digit **1**, or more times

```
pattern = re.compile('(?i)^show me the multiplication table of \d+ from \d+ to \d+$')
```

## Codestyle

1. `StringController()` seems overly complex

   Basically the same can be achieved with `re.match(pattern, input_string)`

   It adds a layer of complexity what is not needed, I would just remove the entire class
2. The extraction of numbers can be greatly simplified

   You could use `re.findall(r'(\d+)', input)` to find the digits in a neater way

   And you could `map(int, iterable)` to convert them to integers

## Alternative

```
INPUT_REGEX = re.compile('(?i)^show me the multiplication table of \d+ from \d+ to \d+$')

def make_table(user_input):
    step, min_range, max_range = map(int, re.findall('(\d+)', user_input))
    return "\n".join(str(step * t) for t in range(min_range, max_range))

def main():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Example string: show me the multiplication table of 8 from 3 to 8\nInput: ')
        print('-'*50)
        if user_input.lower() in ('q', 'quit', 'exit'):
            exit()
        elif re.match(INPUT_REGEX, user_input):
            print(make_table(user_input))
        else:
            print('Use the provided string')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Note I added a quit, might be nice for your user to let them exit in a clean way ;)*